# C++ call a child's method from a vector of parents?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, polymorphism

Say that you have the following class:

```
class Parent
{
   // methods and members go here
};
```

then you create a child based on the parent:

```
class Child : public Parent
{
   public:
      someFunction();
};
```

Now class Parent doesn't have someFunction() but class Child does. Say that you have a vector of Parent classes, and you want to call the child's method, assuming that the vector holds instances of parents and children, given that they're both the same base type.

```
std::vector<Parent> myContainer;
myContainer.push_back(a parent);
myContainer.push_back(a child);

myContainer[1].someFunction();
```

How can I make this work? I'm basically trying to create a vector of parents, but children also go in that vector. I want to call a method that's exclusive for children. Is that possible?

Comment: Your vector holds `Parent` objects. It knows nothing about `Children`.

Comment: @Bugster I would append that your vector contains ONLY parent objects.:) It can not hold child objects. You should at least define a vector of pointers to a polymorphic base class.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to create a container that holds both though? Isn't that one of the perks of polymorphism?

Comment: Polymorphism only works with pointers and references, so if you create a vector of pointers, then it is possible.

Comment: @ivanw that sounds like a great idea actually, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a vector of `Parent` objects. There's no polymorphism here. Vectors contain values. If you want a polymorphic container, you have to use something else.

It's just as if you did

```
Parent myObject;
```

No matter what you do to `myObject` later, it will still be a `Parent`. Even if you do `myObject = Child()`.

Comment: How can I achieve this, though? Would using a vector of pointers work?

Comment: @Bugster Yes, but please don't do that -- the copy and destructor semantics will be all wrong. If you're using c++11, maybe a vector of `unique_ptr`s. Maybe a boost `ptr_vector`.

Comment: The core problem is that C++ provides no way to "clone" an object without knowing its full type. So there's no simple way to create a polymorphic container that has sensible assignment semantics.

Answer (score 6):

Polymorphism only works with pointers and references, so if you create a vector of pointers, then it is possible.

Comment: This is the real answer here. **Polymorphism does not work on values.**

Answer (score 4):

```
class Parent
{
    virtual void foo(){}    //dummy function to make Parent polymorphic
};
class Child : virtual public Parent
{
public:
    void about()
    {
        cout << "Child" << endl;
    }
};
int main()
{

    vector<Parent*> vec;
    vec.push_back(new Parent());
    vec.push_back(new Child());

    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        Child *child = dynamic_cast<Child*>(vec.at(i));
        if (child)
            child->about();     
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This should use `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` instead of raw pointers

Comment: Agree with Matt but otherwise this is what I need, thanks jafar.